# TextureView setSurfaceTexture method requires API 16 level

Tags: android, textureview, android-textureview, android-min-sdk

`TextureView.setSurfaceTexture` method requires API level 16, but my current min 14, how can I use this method in 14, 15 API's?

UPDATE (add code)

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".view.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/videoSurfaceContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextureView
            android:id="@+id/texture_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and in Fragment's onCreateView method:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container, false);
    mVideoContainer = rootView.findViewById(R.id.videoSurfaceContainer);
            mTextureView = (TextureView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.texture_view);
            if (mSurfaceTexture != null) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    mTextureView.setSurfaceTexture(mSurfaceTexture);
                }
            }
            mVideoControllerView.setAnchorView((FrameLayout) mVideoContainer);
            mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
```

Surface texture listener:

```
@Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height) {
        mSurfaceTexture = surfaceTexture;
        Surface surface = new Surface(mSurfaceTexture);
        mMediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height) {
        mSurfaceTexture = surfaceTexture;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
        mSurfaceTexture = surfaceTexture;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
        mSurfaceTexture = surfaceTexture;
    }
```

Comment: can you post some of your code? Can't you overcome this limitation by using api level 14 compatible methods e.g. setting the `SurfaceTextureListener` on your activity?

Comment: Cool, may I ask why you need to call `mTextureView.setSurfaceTexture(mSurfaceTexture);`? Since all work as far as I can understand is getting done inside `onSurfaceTextureAvailable` where you create a new `Surface` with the available `SurfaceTexture ` and set it on the `MediaPlayer` ?

Comment: Without setSurfaceTexture method I have white screen due to orientation change, but sound continues playing. In general I want video won't stop playing when orientation change occurs. My fragment uses  setRetainInstance(true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TextureView.setSurfaceTexture method requires API level 16

**TextureView.setSurfaceTexture** requires ***API Level 16 or higher***.

No there **#is** no way right now  . You must call API Level **16**

Open your `build.gradle` section

```
 defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16    // must use 16 for this 
    targetSdkVersion 19 // set yours as per requirement 

}
```